# Pygame sprite won't move, exits game when key pressed

Tags: python, events, pygame, key, sprite

So I can't get my sprite to jump when the key is pressed.  I've fixed a few errors but now I have one that says: File "/Users/josh/Desktop/fresh/main.py", line 52, in 
screen.blit(player, player_rect)
TypeError: invalid destination position for blit

```
import pygame
from sys import exit
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,400))
pygame.display.set_caption('Shooter Mania')
text = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# 
bg = pygame.image.load('background.png')
# 
player = pygame.image.load('player.png').convert_alpha()
player_rect = player.get_rect(midbottom=(80,300))
playerX = 0
playerY = 0
# 
score_surf = text.render('SCORE:', False, 'white')
score_rect = score_surf.get_rect(center=(400,50))
# 
enemy = pygame.image.load('enemy.png').convert_alpha()
enemy_rect = enemy.get_rect(bottomright=(600,300))
# 
# 
# 

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                player_rect = player_rect.move_ip(0,5)
                print(f'Jump')
    
    screen.blit(bg, (0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'Pink',score_rect)
    screen.blit(score_surf,score_rect)

    enemy_rect.x -= 4

    if enemy_rect.right <= 0:
        enemy_rect.left = 800
    screen.blit(enemy,enemy_rect)

    # if player_rect.y <= 400:
    #     player_rect.y = 300
    # playerX +=1
    # player_rect.y += playerX
    
    screen.blit(player, player_rect)


    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you move your rect, you use [`move_ip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move_ip) which updates the rect in place (hence the name) and returns nothing, i.e. `None`. This then gets assigned to the `player_rect` variable and passed to `screen.blit()`, which fails. The solution is not to use the in-place version of move:

```py
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                player_rect = player_rect.move(0, 5)
                print(f'Jump')
```

This will return the updated rect and assign it to `player_rect`. Alternatively, you could use the in-place version without assignment:

```py
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                player_rect.move_ip(0, 5)
                print(f'Jump')
```